# Replace every " with \" in Lua

Tags: replace, lua, escaping

[X-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/): I want to dump an *entire* lua-script to a single string-line, which can be compiled into a C-Program afterwards.

**Y-Problem**: How can you replace every `"` with `\"` ?

I think it makes sense to try something like this

`data = string.gsub(line, "c", "\c")`
where c *is* the `"`-character. But this does not work of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape both quotes and backslashes, if I understand your Y problem:

```
data = string.gsub(line, "\"", "\\\"")
```

or use the other single quotes (still escape the backslash):

```
data = string.gsub(line, '"', '\\"')
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution to your *X-Problem* is to safely escape any sequence that could interfere with the interpreter.

Lua has the `%q` option for [string.format](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.format) that will format and escape the provided string in such a way, that it can be safely read back by Lua. It should be also true for your C interpreter.

---

Example string: `This \string's truly"tricky`

If you just enclosed it in either single or double-quotes, there'd still be a quote that ended the string early. Also there's the invalid escape sequence `\s`.

Imagine this string was already properly handled in Lua, so we'll just pass it as a parameter:
`string.format("%q", 'This \\string\'s truly"tricky')`

returns (notice, I used single-quotes in code input):

`"This \\string's truly\"tricky"`

Now that's a completely valid Lua string that can be written and read from a file. No need to manually escape every special character and risk implementation mistakes.

---

To correctly implement your *Y* approach, to escape (invalid) characters with `\`, use [proper pattern matching](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial) to replace the captured string with a prefix+captured string:

`string.gsub('he"ll"o', "[\"']", "\\%1") -- will prepend backslash to any quote`